# check valid email address even its catch all email hosts

Tags: java, node.js, email, smtp, tcp

I wanted to know given email Id is exist or not. Even the email domain configured in catch all.

For example:

```
user@domain.com is given.
domain.com is catch all SMTP domain
domain.com is valid but user is not registered it.
given email id is not valid(excepted answer)
```

Comment: whether it exists, or whether it is a valid email address? you can only verify whether it exists by mailing it, and seeing whether the mail arrives or throws an exception

Comment: you can check to see if the email address is in the correct format, but as @Stultuske said the only way to throw an exception is to try and send the mail and handle the result

Comment: Shall we check a valid email address Without sending mail?
Sending mail and check whether its bounce or not - I think this way need some sec to checks right?

Answer (score 0):

See if MX Record checking can help you  - 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html

Comment: Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There are online applications (some of them based on MX Record) to verify an email address - like http://verify-email.org/

Another example - http://validateemailaddress.org/

Can you please check whether they have a published API/webservice that can be consumed in your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check an email address every now and then, just use the free MailboxValidator demo page.

http://www.mailboxvalidator.com/demo

But if you require an API, you can sign up for the free API at

http://www.mailboxvalidator.com/plans#api

If you use the API, you can get the following result fields:

"domain" : This is the domain of the email address.

"is_free" : This indicates if the email address is from a free email provider like Gmail or Hotmail.

"is_syntax" : This indicates whether the email address is syntactically correct.

"is_domain" : This indicates whether the email address has a valid MX record in its DNS entries.

"is_smtp" : This indicates whether the mail servers specified in the MX records are responding to connections.

"is_verified" : This indicates whether the mail server confirms that the email address actually exist.

"is_server_down" : This indicates whether the mail server is currently down or unresponsive.

"is_greylisted" : This indicates whether the mail server employs greylisting where an email has to be sent a second time at a later time.

"is_disposable" : This indicates whether the email address is a temporary one from a disposable email provider.

"is_suppressed" : This indicates whether the email address is in our blacklist.

"is_role" : This indicates whether the email address is a role-based email address like admin@example.net, webmaster@example.net or support@example.net.

"is_high_risk" : This indicates whether the email address contains high risk keywords.

"is_catchall" : This indicates whether the email address is a catch-all address.

"mailboxvalidator_score" : Email address reputation score. Score > 0.70 means good; score > 0.40 means fair; score ≤ 0.40 means poor.

"time_taken" : The time taken to get the results in seconds.

"status" : This indicates whether our system think the email address is valid based on all the previous fields.